# Create a second WebAccess RDS connection to servers already in a collection

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-gateway

All of our staff who are working from home use Windows RD Web Access to connect in to our Remote Desktop Servers.
We currently have a 2012-r2 RD Broker with 1 collection consisting of 5 RDS 2012-r2 Servers and a second collection with just a Remote Apps Server. Currently the RDS collection is set-up to display the RDS session across all monitors available to the users machine that they are connecting from.

I need to set-up a second connection that when connecting will only use one monitor from the users machine when open the RDS Connection. This is so that users can have Video Conference hosted on their local machine on one monitor and the RDS connection on another. Not all users will need this so I can't just edit the existing connection.

I cannot create a second collection on the Broker as when I go through the create a new Collection wizard no servers appear until the "RD Session Host" step (presumably because they are all part of the first collection).

I cannot see anywhere in the properties of the first Collection to set-up a second RDS connection for that collection (where I can then change the property under Client Setting --> Max rediredcted Monitor).

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can get a second connection set-up for the same collection?

---

*EDIT following Swisstone's Answer.*

When the user open the RDP Connection from the WebAcess page they don't get to save the RDP connection as a RDP file. The users can only see the following options:

Is there a way to have the monitors option added to the "Show Details" section so that users can specify this?

[image: WebAcces RDP Options]

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a RD Session Host server to more than 1 collection.

However, your question is mainly about a client issue: in the Remote Desktop Connection client, just go to the "Display" tab, and uncheck "Use all my monitors for the remote session"

Comment: I've edited my above post to to include more information about your answer.